# GitLab CE refuses to successfully send emails

Tags: gitlab, actionmailer

I've spent hours poring over various Stack Overflow threads and GitLab documentation trying to simply get SMTP email sending in GitLab to work. Unfortunately, I've been unsuccessful.

I spun up a GitLab CE instance from the 9.5.4 AWS marketplace AMI, then upgraded it to the latest version. The help page reports this version: `GitLab Community Edition 10.2.4 ba9acca`. I am running this GitLab instance from a private EC2 instance that is accessed by connecting to a VPN. The GitLab instance uses an SNAT instance to reach the internet. My email domain is `mydomain.com` and the internal GitLab domain is `gitlab.corp.mydomain.com`.

What's confusing is that there are apparently two places where SMTP settings can be specified: `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb`. Some settings exist in both places. I've seen reference to "Omnibus" using the `gitlab.rb` settings while "built from source" uses `smtp_settings.rb`; I am not sure which settings I am supposed to use, so I have settings specified in both places.

Relevant `gitlab.rb` excerpt:

```rb
### Email Settings
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@mydomain.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'GitLab'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_subject_suffix'] = ''

### GitLab email server settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html
###! **Use smtp instead of sendmail/postfix.**

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.office365.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "me@mydomain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "<redacted>"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "mydomain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false

###! **Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert'**
###! Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
```

`smtp_settings.rb`:

```rb
# To enable smtp email delivery for your GitLab instance do the following:
# 1. Rename this file to smtp_settings.rb
# 2. Edit settings inside this file
# 3. Restart GitLab instance
#
# For full list of options and their values see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
#
# If you change this file in a Merge Request, please also create a Merge Request on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests

if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.office365.com",
    port: 587,
    user_name: "me@mydomain.com",
    password: "<redacted>",
    domain: "mydomain.com",
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    openssl_verify_mode: 'none', # See ActionMailer documentation for other possible options
  }
end
```

Using `telnet` from the GitLab instance, I verified that I am able to establish an outbound connection to `smtp.office365.com` on port 587.

I found a page [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/troubleshooting/debug.html) that explains how to test email sending. After I executed the test, I noticed that the `From` and `Reply-To` headers are incorrect, which causes Office 365 to correctly reject my email as being from an invalid sender:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.8)
irb(main):001:0> Notify.test_email('me@mydomain.com', 'Subject', 'Body').deliver_now

Notify#test_email: processed outbound mail in 120.6ms

Sent mail to me@mydomain.com (14573.5ms)
Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2017 04:42:39 +0000
From: GitLab <gitlab@gitlab.corp.mydomain.com>
Reply-To: GitLab <noreply@gitlab.corp.mydomain.com>
To: me@mydomain.com
Message-ID: <redacted>
Subject: Subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Body</p></body></html>

Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender [CY1PR13MB0380.namprd13.prod.outlook.com]

        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:974:in `check_response'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:919:in `data'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:664:in `block in send_message'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:859:in `rcptto_list'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:664:in `send_message'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `block in deliver!'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:522:in `start'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:111:in `deliver!'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:2149:in `do_delivery'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:237:in `block in deliver'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in deliver_mail'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:541:in `deliver_mail'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:237:in `deliver'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.8/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
        from (irb):1
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea where those `From` and `Reply-To` addresses are coming from. They do not appear in my `gitlab.rb` configuration. I am sure this is why the email sending is failing.

Questions:

- What's going on here?
- Where does GitLab log this activity?
- Why are the same settings specified in two different places?

Comment: Just to be clear your `gitlab.rb` file is all comments (`#` before everything). Is that actually how it is?

Comment: Oh, wow, am I dumb! Ruby's not my specialty, and it sure shows here. I'll fix this and reply if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I uncommented all the settings, did a full `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`, and unfortunately it still doesn't work. The `From` and `Reply-To` addresses are still `gitlab@gitlab.corp.mydomain.com`.

Comment: I've updated the post to remove the erroneous comments.

Comment: I'm looking at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/93e96c3fcf30c476df332a7e5e762134ffb5da3e/app/mailers/base_mailer.rb to determine where it's pulling these settings from. It looks like they are pulled from the GitLab config, which is now set correctly.

Comment: I fixed it. I commented out the SMTP settings in `gitlab.rb` since it looks like they were unused. Then, I rebooted the server, as it seems like `sudo gitlab-ctl restart` was not enough to make the new settings take effect. The test email was sent successfully. I will leave the question open in the hopes that the other two questions are answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is, like you have said in your comments, that you have commented your settings. Further you should notice that for Omnibus installs of Gitlab the only settings you should use is `gitlab.rb`.

This file is used to generate the other settings files like `smtp_settings`. 
The regeneration of files will be executed if you run the command `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, this will also be triggered when you upgrade your instance.

Comment: `smtp_settings.rb` was not being generated by `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. I had to create my own file from the example file in the same directory.

Comment: I have tested it right now. Gitlab definitly create a `smtp_settings.rb`file if you run the command. Have you run it as `root` or with the `sudo` prefix?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it does create the file. I think I am running into a different issue where GitLab's configuration is somehow resetting after I reboot the EC2 instance; for example, my `external_url` keeps resetting to `https://<elasticip>` from `https://gitlab.corp.mydomain.com`.